# Can The App Include Biometric Login With Firebase?

Tags: flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication, biometrics

Just Wondering, Is there a way to Login to Firebase with Biometrics Like Fingerprint or Facial Login ?

Comment: Firebase does not provide any support for biometric authentication, however, there are third-party libraries that can be used, for flutter you can use https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication does not directly support anything other than the options you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).  There are no provided APIs for specific types of authentication outside of the providers you see (for example, email/pw, Google, Facebook, etc).  Some devices might come with their own biometric sign-ins integrated with one of supported providers, but Firebase would not deal directly with those.

Comment: So How can I prepare my app to deal with these phones ?

Comment: I don't know.  I suggest using the APIs provided on the devices by the operating system.  Firebase was designed to care about identifying the user across mulitple devices and operating systems.  It doesn't care about one user's specific biometrics on a specific device.  It's a different concern entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Firebase login with email and password. What you can do on initial login/registration is store the email and password in keychain/keystore. You can use the flutter_secure_storage package from pub.dev. Then on the next login you can use the local_auth package also from pub.dev. From there if local_auth is available and if its successful you can then pass in the credentials from keychain/keystore over to Firebase login with email and password method.